# Compaq ProLiant DL580 boot menu?

Tags: boot, hp

I want to boot a CD on the given server.

It's only booting via network.

F10 or F9 on Compaq logo screen doesn't work, neither F1.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is a Compaq G1 or G2? or was this after the HP Mergers and therefore a G3/4/5/6 ?

Comment: What steps have you taken before posting here? What Generation is you DL580? Have you read the manual?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a G1 server (white/beige-colored DL580 with Compaq logos), the BIOS is actually supposed to be a special partition on the hard drive. This is installed via the appropriate Compaq Smart Start CD of the era (v5.x, I think). Without this system partition or the Smart Start CD, you won't have BIOS access.

Answer (score 1):

It's a vague questions, and I'm at home so not gonna reboot anything remotely right now...

Here's a recent user guide for the [ROM-Based Setup Utility (pdf)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00191707/c00191707.pdf)

The details will be different depending on what generation the server is, but it looks like you could go in and take out the optical drive as possible IPL location.